# Question about Bull queue : @OnQueueCompleted() listening for one completed job?

Tags: node.js, queue, nestjs, priority-queue, bull-queue

If I use the @OnQueueCompleted(), so I can get the response from one completed job in the queue, am I right?
Or the @Onqueuecompleted() only responds when all jobs in the queue are completed.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As the name implies, `@OnQueueCompleted()` decorator factory refers to the `'completed'` event from Bull. Thus, your method will be called every time a job is completed in the queue.

Ref: https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/edfbd163991c212dd6548875c22f2745f897ae28/test/test_getters.js#L93-L115

Comment: Thanks! So, for the @OnQueueFailed(), if one job is failed the first time，it calls the @OnQueueFailed() then wait for 1s and try the second time; it fails and calls @OnQueueFailed() again. It will wait for 2s and try the third time; this time, it is completed and call @OnQueueCompleted().  Am I right? Here is setting: {attempts: 5,backoff: { type: 'exponential',delay: 1000, }

Comment: I didn't use Bull yet tbh, so I'm not sure how this `exponential`. works. The only think I know is that if the job fails, then the method annotaed with `@OnQueueFailed()` will be called